# Knockout click binding with mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to use the click binding to increment and subtract a value in a text binding by one. I am not sure how to reference myNumber.

html:

```
<a data-bind="click: increment">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"> </i>
</a>
<div data-bind="text: myNumber"></div>
<a data-bind="click: subtract">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"> </i>
</a>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function increment(result){
        result.myNumber ++;
    }
    function subtract(result){
        result.myNumber --;
    }
    $.getJSON("/app/api/", function(result) {

        function viewModel() {
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
    })
    .error(function () { alert("error"); });
</script>
```

Comment: you have text: myNumber in your data-binding, where is it in the code ???

Comment: It gets it from the viewModel. That bit works fine

Answer (score 0):

You don't increment an observable as if it were a number. It is a setter/getter.
Also, the functions you bind need to be part of the viewmodel. You can do that inside your `getJSON` callback before `applyBindings`.

```js
vm = {
  myNumber: ko.observable(3),
  increment: function(result) {
    result.myNumber(result.myNumber() + 1);
  },
  subtract: function(result) {
    result.myNumber(result.myNumber() - 1);
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: increment">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"> </i>
</a>
<div data-bind="text: myNumber"></div>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: subtract">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"> </i>
</a>
```

Comment: Imho @royJ we can have this simple operation done even better (tough you may aware) rather stuffing up the view (not needed here) . something like this http://jsfiddle.net/5h3vvn3q/ .

Comment: @supercool Oops! The `bind` wasn't needed. That was left over from doing it a different way. I wanted to keep things as much like the OP as possible, which is why I use `result`.

Comment: ooh i see now @royJ i just seen the OP question  :D LoL .  cheers